# Define BASE tag in html using php

Tags: php

I want to define the BASE tag in html using PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php echo LANG; ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php echo CHARSET; ?>">
    <base href="<?php echo BASE; ?>">
</head>
....
```

Did some research here, and came up with this.

```
config.inc.php

define('LANG', 'es_ES');
define('CHARSET', 'utf-8');
define('SERVER_SERVER_NAME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('SERVER_PHP_SELF', dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

define('BASE', SERVER_SERVER_NAME . SERVER_PHP_SELF . '/');
```

2 questions:

1. Is there a way to define the keyword `http`? Sometimes it can be `https` and hardcoding that keyword is a bad idea.
2. Should i define the BASE value by ending it with a slash or not ?

Any improvements on this very simple code?

Thanks

Comment: just use `//` it will auto populate to either `http` or `https` and this for anything at all, be it JS scripts, images, etc. that's what I do.

Comment: ....like Fred said ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Just leave the protocol out, and start the URL with `//`. It will then default to the protocol of the document that contains it.
2. The `<base>` URL should end with a `/` if you want it to specify a folder.

Comment: [That's what I said...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396937/define-base-tag-in-html-using-php#comment73854794_43396937) - 2 mins. prior ;-)

Comment: I was typing my answer at the same time as you were commenting. I needed to do some googling to check the `<base>` part, so I didn't post it immediately.

Comment: Seeing http://stackoverflow.com/a/1889957/1415724 shows potential problems with the `<base>` tag with certain versions of IE.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It says the problem is in IE6. That's prehistoric. IE8 is the oldest version anyone has even the slightest concern about, and even that is mostly dwindling.